# variable offsets from stack/frame pointer in MIPS

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, mips

I was wondering about how to specify variable declaration from C to MIPS, if I don't initialise them. I suppose that with initialisation it would be something like this:

```
# C code
int x = 7;

# MIPS code
.data
x: .word 7
```

But what if my C code looks something like this:

```
int x;

void main() {
.
.
x = 7;
.
.
}
```

Should I devote some memory in the stack pointer ($sp) when declaring 'x', and then move the pointer back to 'x' when I'm assigning it to 7? If yes, how would I know how much to increment the pointer in order to reach the location of 'x' in $sp? For all I know, alot of staff has already happened before assigning 'x' to 7.

**Edit:**

Sorry about the confusion. My question wasn't specifically about Global variables. So the code can also be something like this:

```
void main() {
.
.
int x;
.
.
x = 7; # or simply x;
.
.
}
```

As people mentioned in the comment, it needs to be stack allocated. So I guess my question is regarding the amount that I need to increment the stack pointer. Should I somehow remember the offset to "x" and every time I wanna use it, I do something like:

```
addi $sp, $sp, x_offset
lw $t0, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, -x_offset
```

Am I understanding the concept right?

Comment: BTW, why don't you just use `gcc -O0 -S codeTest.c` to watch how compilers do it in "naive" non-optimized way, just outputting some code (quite representing the internal compiler structure of parsed C source)? You may also want to try `-O3` to see how it then cut trough this tree of data to emit "optimal" (best the compiler can) machine code to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why `x` would be stack-allocated in the second case. It's still a global variable.

If you want to reserve some space in the data section without explicitly giving it any value, use the `.space` directive (assuming the GNU assembler is used):

```
.data
x: .space 4   # reserve space for 4 bytes == 1 word
```

I believe that `x` is guaranteed to have an initial value of 0 in this case.

Note that `x` would still occupy space in your object file / executable. If you want to avoid the uninitialized variables taking up space in the executable, place them in the `.bss` section and reserve space with `.comm`/`.lcomm`:

```
.bss
.lcomm x,4
```

You would then usually have some code in your startup code (`crt0` or whatever you're calling it) that zeroes the entire `.bss` section at startup.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about .space. I like the idea. But what if 'x' is declared inside the main function? Also, if I understand correctly C allows for multiple declaration of the same variable as long as they are not in the same scope. What if 'x' is declared both inside and outside the main function? If in my code generator, I print "x: .space 4" twice, won't I get an error in MIPS?

Comment: My answer was regarding uninitialized globals. Local variables would be stack-allocated (except for static locals).

Comment: @Babak in C declared inside scope is local (usually compiled as stack variable, but that's not required by C language, compiler may as well decide to put it into `.data/.bss` (but that doesn't make sense) or keep it just as CPU register (can happen in real world). When you declare `x` twice in different scopes, they are actually different variables (C compiler doesn't have problem to pick the correct one in particular scope, for machine it's easy, worse for reader). In most of the assemblers you can not do the same stunt, once the symbol name is defined - it's usually global for that ASM file.

Comment: @Babak *"If in my code generator, I print "x: .space 4" twice, won't I get an error in MIPS?"* Yes, you will, you can't generate assembly code for C source in such naive way, that would work only for the simplest C sources. There are many more issues with straightforward "short piece of C" => "few asm ops" way of compilation, not just variable names. Functions overloading for example. Different `struct` members with same name, etc...

Comment: Thank you both. I guess I asked my question wrong. I am now differentiating between global and local variables. I edited the question. can you take a look?